# Is Ubuntu 14.04 using systemd?

Tags: 14.04, init, systemd

There was a lot of discussion about the init system for 14.04 before it was released, but I cannot find any site that explains the outcome finally.

So is Ubuntu 14.04 using systemd now?

Comment: Related: [How can I replace upstart with systemd?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/420917/how-can-i-replace-upstart-with-systemd)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses Upstart as the init system, the plan to switch to systemd is planned for 14.10+. There are parts of "systemd" that have been used in Ubuntu for a long time, but for most intents and purposes when people say "systemd" they mean systemd-as-init.

Here's some background info:

- http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-1403/meeting/22156/core-1403-systemd-transition/
- http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1406/meeting/22277/ubuntu-server-plans-around-systemd/

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 14):

To show what init process is enabled:

```
# readlink /sbin/init
```

By default on 14.04 and 14.10 it's "upstart"

Changing this would involve *alot* more configuration than just changing this symlink so don't do that. This file is nearly always a simlink. In this case the link path does not start with `/` so this is a path relative to the symlink file to `/sbin/upstart`.

To confuse matters systemd is installed for other things but not used as init. It is in `/bin` not `/sbin`. But systemd has installed itself as init in man / help, so:

```
# man init
```

Brings up docs on systemd (as of Dec 22, 2014) This is *very* confusing ! You want:

```
# man upstart
```

This will give you the docs for init as they should be.

Good luck getting started. (pun ah ah)

Comment: Actually, on my Ubuntu 14.04.2 Server `/sbin/init` it's an executable binary, so that readlink trick doesn't work. Also, `man init` gives me upstart man page. Maybe something has changed?

Comment: The `readlink /sbin/init` didn't work for me on 14.04 either. Just blank output. The `man init` did the trick.

Comment: I filed a bug report for the documentation. It sounds like it may have been fixed, and I suspect init was changed to be a hard link rather than a relative soft link which would barely improve boot time. I've since moved on from 14.04 so I can't comment definitively.

Comment: Running `/sbin/init --version` seems to work. I've tested on 1404  and systemd , both return the correct init system

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Ubuntu vivid (15.04) upstart is still default, but, you can easily switch between upstart and systemd at will, since both packages are installed at present:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

In ubuntu 15.10 systemd is the default, but you still can choose upstart each boottime in the grub menu