# Unable to locate package libsystemd-dev

Tags: 14.04, server, package-management, openstack

I am trying to install devstack on Ubuntu server 14.04.

I had a few problems before with HOST_IP, GIT_BASE and some updates... I fixed all of them, but now I am stuck on this one. I tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get install libsystemd-dev`, and I get

```
E: unable to locate package libsystemd-dev
```

Comment: afaik 14.04 does not use systemd...

Comment: @Zanna what version does use it?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/490946/is-ubuntu-14-04-using-systemd  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/420917/how-can-i-replace-upstart-with-systemd

Comment: 15.04 and above.

Comment: 16.04, 16.10 and 17.04 are the currently supported versions using systemd

Comment: thank you all for your answers! I'll try with a higher version of ubuntu and i will reply if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that Ubuntu version 14.04 doesn't use systemd packages.

I tried it out on 16.04 and it is working correctly now. I want to thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 14.04 run

```
sudo apt-get install libsystemd-daemon-dev
```