# Unable to boot after installing systemd-services and changing the init parameter on boot

Tags: boot, kernel, systemd

I tried two different methods but could not install `systemd`

1st method from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/420979/294611), 2nd method from [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-and-test-systemd-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

Confirmation that `systemd` is not installed:

```
edward@computer:~$ file /lib/systemd/systemd
/lib/systemd/systemd: ERROR: cannot open `/lib/systemd/systemd' (No such file or directory)
```

Another confirmation:

[image]

I'm following the methods proposed in https://askubuntu.com/a/420979/294611 (against this question was closed as duplicated to), yet for some reason my system doesn't boot.

Comment: As far as I know, systemd is not yet supported on Ubuntu. If you want to try it, boot Fedora or Arch linux.

Comment: And from - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd#Warning.21_Experimental_code - "Warning! Experimental code
systemd is under active development in Ubuntu although the rough plan would be to default to systemd during development of 15.04. If you want to help it's best to be running 15.04. (14.10 might be doable as well..)"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen there is method given in the first link I gave right ? then why cant we try it ?

Comment: You are welcome to try it, but see the FAQ here regarding code in development see - http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "Questions that you should avoid: ... <clip> ...
Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues)." systemd is experimental code at this time, ready for 15.04, which is ubuntu +1

Comment: @bodhi.zazen if trying `systemd` is off-topic then why there is a method to try it out in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/420979/294611) ?

Comment: Even better, boot Fedora, systemd works fine in Fedora. Also the fedora and arch documentation are far better then the Debian or Ubuntu documentation at this time. If you insist on trying it on Ubuntu your experience will be less then optimal.

Comment: Ask on meta for an opinion on what is on and off topic. I already gave you a link to the FAQ as a reference

Comment: @bodhi.zazen thanks sir for your comments, but I am not looking for optimal-experience. please help according question

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am not asking about off-topic stuff. I am stating that how to install `systemd` already is given in that answer, its not working for me. please read the question

Comment: well, you installed it, and it broke. So now you are asking how to fix it, ie for support. I asked for clarification on this topic on meta - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12349/systemd-on-or-off-topic feel free to weigh in on that discussion.

Comment: Are you using 14.10? Have you installed both the `systemd-sysv` and `systemd` packages?

Comment: @alexander255 I mentioned in question I have ubuntu 14.04 but someone edited it

Comment: @alexander255 I am not sure, please look at both the links, I tried installing `systemd` by two methods

Comment: Your problem isn´t installing systemd, but using systemd as init. Please, leave the title as is.

Comment: @Braiam my problem is installing systemd ! i cannot find `systemd` after installing it ! which means I could not install it !

Comment: No, the problem comes *after* you followed the procedure to install the package. If you followed the instructions installing `systemd-services` you in theory have systemd for all proposes. The problem you are facing is because you are trying to use systemd as init.

Comment: This is why I wanted you to change the title... now is closed as duplicated of the question you are following.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I´m not sure what Canonical did. When I installed systemd on my Raring installation (as seen [in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420917/how-can-i-replace-upstart-with-systemd/420979#comment705748_420979)), the binary *was there*. Now it isn´t anywhere, and the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_208-8ubuntu8/changelog) before Utopic version 208-8ubuntu1 is useless (utopic does have the [binary there](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=utopic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=%2Flib%2Fsystemd%2Fsystemd&searchon=contents)), since they just imported the package from Debian, which is a blessing to Utopic users, since the method described in the answer works for them.

Trusty changelogs doesn´t either explain what could happened either. I checked the [BZR repository](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty) looking for clues directly about what happened with the package. There´s a [systemd.install](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/debian/systemd.install) file in the debian\ directory, yet the package itself doesn´t exist in repositories; the systemv-init package which replace `/sbin/init` with a link to systemd binary [indeed points to `/lib/systemd/systemd`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/debian/systemd-sysv.links), which only adds to my confusion. The [control file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/debian/control#L46) has an entry for the systemd package too. The systemd.link file [also links](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/systemd/trusty/view/head:/debian/systemd.links#L58) to `/lib/systemd/systemd` from the `/bin` directory.

All evidence points that systemd package is necesary to get systemd binary, yet **the package itself is not provided anywhere for trusty**. This has lead me to think that Canonical decided to not provide systemd binary for releases before trusty in their repositories, which is hinted by the fact that **if you build the systemd debian source package that Ubuntu provides you will get the systemd package and all necesary binaries to boot using systemd as init**.

So, to solve the problem you are facing, because the binary simply isn´t there, you just need to remove the `init` of your kernel parameters and revert the changes you have done to your `/etc/default/grub` file and run sudo `update-grub`, in summary everything you have done in order to replace upstart with systemd. Afterwards, is your call: upgrade to utopic, leave it as it is, or build systemd package from debian sources.

For now, I would only recommend Utopic and later users to install systemd, as before that, there´s no sure fire way to install systemd and replace the init with the packages provided by Canonical/Ubuntu repositories.