# Why is systemd installed and running by default on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upstart, systemd

According to my [research](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420917/how-can-i-replace-upstart-with-systemd), "systemd doesn't work with 14.04".

However, on all my Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty" machines, systemd is running:

```
jay@host:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

So if it doesn't work with Trusty, why on earth is systemd installed and running?

```
jay@host:~$ dpkg -l | grep systemd
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64       204-5ubuntu20.11  amd64  system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libsystemd-daemon0:amd64   204-5ubuntu20.11  amd64  systemd utility library
ii  libsystemd-login0:amd64    204-5ubuntu20.11  amd64  systemd login utility library
ii  systemd-services           204-5ubuntu20.11  amd64  systemd runtime services
ii  systemd-shim               6-2bzr1           amd64  shim for systemd
```

.

```
jay@host:~$ ps -ef | grep systemd
root       408     1  0 Jun17 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
root       808     1  0 Jun17 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
jay  13544 13242  0 12:07 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto systemd
```