# How can I replace systemd with upstart?

Tags: systemd, init

I found this : 
[How can I replace upstart with systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420917/how-can-i-replace-upstart-with-systemd)

but I would like the other way around.

The reason is that I spend quite a time learning the basic init process and I am pretty much accustomed to the "service" commands. I really dont care about 10 - 20 millisecond or even 1 -2 seconds of late boot up. I just need some clarity in the init process and want to stick to the old system..

Is it possible to do this at the boot time using grub maybe, which blacklists systemd and just runs the 14.04 init routines ( I guess it was a mix of upstart and sysvinit )?

I found something, but dont know how to proceed further:

In the /etc/grub.d/10_linux, I find an entry with

```
SUPPORTED_INITS="sysvinit:/lib/sysvinit/init systemd:/lib/systemd/systemd upstart:/sbin/upstart"$
```

Comment: [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) describes the process of switching back from `systemd` to `upstart`. Does that help?

Comment: @Jos: NO, I did not find the word upstart in the file 10_linux.

Comment: @muru: you are repeating. As I said, there is no option of starting with upstart in grub. I could edit the file, but need to know what should I write there, so that upstart as init is selected.

Comment: :shrug: I have boot entries with upstart in them. What does `grep -i upstart /boot/grub/grub.cfg` output?

Comment: @muru : strange, i have boot entries with upstart in /boot/grub but not in in /etc/grub.d/ ! I was of the impression , that the grub.cfg is generated from grub.d.. Do you have upstart boot entries in grub.d?

Comment: anyhow, I will give it a try and reboot.

Comment: I followed the link. intstalled upstart-sysv and rebooted. Unfortunately, the boot process stucks at init ramdisk.

Comment: @heynnema : your analogy is foolish. but lets not dig into philosophy and remain to question and answers. I chose upstart and as I wrote, it got stuck into the init ramblock.. the kernel wont boot. However, I will install 14.04 and I guess, all is good.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to continue to run `Upstart` should be considered temporary. Over time (or already?) some projects which will quit providing Upstart init scripts, so your transition to systemd will happen eventually if you stick with Ubuntu.

However, the `service` command continues to work with `systemd` on Ubuntu 16.04 and beyond as it did before with Upstart.  I expect this command will exist for a while.

If your primary concern is being able to use the `service` command, there is no need to switch back to Upstart for that.